# getting started with mootools in webstorm

Tags: mootools, webstorm

Sow how to include mootools js files in my project so there are no 'Class is not defined' errors?

The [getting started page](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-mootools/) starts with selecting an element, but I don't even know how to get it working in the IDE...

Edit: I have added MooTools as an external library through JavaScript -> Libriaries and it is present as such. My question is how to get it in my project, I haven't been able to find any .js files.

Comment: Do you know how to add libraries in webstorm? You need some mootools library like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>` in your files.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: nothing in the source code of the rendered page? or in the console/resources/script?

Comment: I ended up using oops.js instead of mootools

Comment: ok, so maybe better to delete this question

Comment: Well it would still be nice if somewhere it's explained how to use external libraries in Webstorm. You'd expect that the build-in feature to install a package also allows you to use in in your project.